# How to execute bash command with sudo privileges in Java?

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm using ProcessBuilder to execute bash commands:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("gedit").start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to make something like this:

```
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "gedit").start();
```

How to pass superuser password to bash?

`("gksudo", "gedit")` will not do the trick, because it was deleted since Ubuntu 13.04 and I need to do this with available by default commands.

EDIT

gksudo came back to Ubuntu 13.04 with the last update.

Comment: What a GREAT idea to remove gksudo! Congratulations, Ubuntu! As a workaround I can suggest ``xterm -e 'sudo -i gedit'``. Or install ``gksu`` package. Or even run your whole java program as root.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko using xterm is actually a good idea... Thanks. `sudo app.jar` will work as it should? From the opening application to closing it?

Comment: Yeah, ``sudo app.jar`` should give it sudo priveleges for everything. Just note that everything you do is going to be under root, so if you create a file from your java program it wont be visible to other users because user will have no privileges for it. Just take care of it.

Comment: Solution here: http://codeflex.co/java-run-sudo-command-on-remote-linux-host/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you can use this, but I'm a bit hesitant to post it. So I'll just say:

**Use this at your own risk, not recommended, don't sue me, etc...**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo password| sudo -S ls"};
    Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    String line;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bash/bin": error=2`

When I changed `/bash/bin` to `bash` it compiles without errors but with any effect at all.

Comment: Yes, that's because 'echo password' should be replaced by echoing your real password. I fixed the /bin/bash thing also.

Comment: I know that I should replace it and I did ;)
Still not working. It is just <terminated> and nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, now it is working :)

`{"/bin/bash","-c","echo \"password\"| sudo -S ls"};`

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I also just tested it again! For me it was working/not working because my sudo was remembering me. Uncached it using sudo -K. Could you upvote so people know this is the answer?

Comment: Btw, I didn't have to escape the quotes, not sure if that's needed. Glad it works!

Comment: @EricPragt It requires 15 reputation :( But I accepted this answer :)

Comment: This `String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo password| sudo -S ls"};` works perfectly for me! Thanks!!

Comment: This code works perfectly, but is not a good solution, because it exposes the password in the command line and other process can see it.

Comment: @passerbywhu this comment made my day :-) Thanks for saying that!

Comment: @kato2 / All,

I could see only the "sudo -S <command>" and the child process <command> in the process list. I could not see the password that is being echoed here. Do we have any ways of checking it? and do we have any other possible solution that is industry standard?

Note : I do not hard code the password & is echoed from a different input source.

Answer (score 14):

Edit /etc/sudoers with visudo and grant your user a NOPASSWD right for a specific script:

username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/yourscript.sh

Comment: This is the only viable option.

Comment: Or add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d` as suggested by armnotstrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090432/2021763

Answer (score 9):

My solution, doesn't exposes the password in the command line, it just feed the password to the output stream of the process. This is a more flexible solution because allows you to request the password to the user when it is needed.

```
public static boolean runWithPrivileges() {
    InputStreamReader input;
    OutputStreamWriter output;

    try {
        //Create the process and start it.
        Process pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/sudo -S /bin/cat /etc/sudoers 2>&1"}).start();
        output = new OutputStreamWriter(pb.getOutputStream());
        input = new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream());

        int bytes, tryies = 0;
        char buffer[] = new char[1024];
        while ((bytes = input.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            if(bytes == 0)
                continue;
            //Output the data to console, for debug purposes
            String data = String.valueOf(buffer, 0, bytes);
            System.out.println(data);
            // Check for password request
            if (data.contains("[sudo] password")) {
                // Here you can request the password to user using JOPtionPane or System.console().readPassword();
                // I'm just hard coding the password, but in real it's not good.
                char password[] = new char[]{'t','e','s','t'};
                output.write(password);
                output.write('\n');
                output.flush();
                // erase password data, to avoid security issues.
                Arrays.fill(password, '\0');
                tryies++;
            }
        }

        return tryies < 3;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: By slightly modifying the Code I think this does the best job. What I do especially like about this solution is the security issue being solved as you do not print the password in the Console directly.

Answer (score 7):

Do not try to write a system password plainly in a file, especially for a user that have the sudo privilege, just as @jointEffort answered, issued privilege should be solved by system administrators not by app writers.

`sudo` allow you to grant privileges for specific command to specific user, which is precisely enough, check [this post](http://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/)

and you can choose to manage the privilege in a separated file other than the main **sudoers** file if you want just append `#includedirs /etc/sudoers.d/` in the main `/etc/sudoers` file(most Linux distributions have already done that) and make a file like `ifconfig-user` with:

```
 USER_NAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

Another thing, remember to edit the config file with `visudo` in case you lost control of your system when there is syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but i just want to put this here:

you can use `sudo -S *command*` as a command that you pass to create the Process instance. Then get the output stream and write the password to it, and add at the end of it a new line and a c. return (`\n\r`). The return may not be required but i passed it just in case. Also it is a good idea to flush the stream, to make sure everything is written to it. I've done it a few times and it works like a charm. And DO NOT forget to close streams :).

Answer (score 1):

Once you spawn a process you can extract the input and output streams. Just feed the password to the output stream (you output it into the proccess's input). So the code would look something like -

```
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("gedit").start();
OutputStream out = pb.getOutputStream();
out.write(password);
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work. The sudo command needs to get the command from the actual keyboard, not from an input stream...

Comment: @ErikPragt Are you sure? I've never heard of something like that. From what I understand the sudo command shouldnt have a clue where its coming from, it just gets it from an input stream and thats it.

Comment: Well, if you look at the -S option in Sudo, I think that sort of implies that: "-S The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.". That is, unless I read this wrong. But no, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ErikPragt So he can just tack on a newline char at the end of the output.

Comment: @Dgrin91, I tried your solution on my mac, but it doesn't work, the password is not passed to the process. See here: https://gist.github.com/bodiam/6502781

Comment: @VareZon Not really sure. Try putting a newline at the end. It could very well be that Erik is right.

Comment: this works just fine with `sudo -S`. Also see @kato2's answer.