# Unable to execute terminal command in cent os using java

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat8

While i am trying to run below java code ,getting an exception

Java code :-

```
String status;
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo\t/etc/init.d/idns status");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        status = stdInput.readLine();
    if (status.equals("gtd is stopped")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo\t/etc/init.d/idns   start");
            logger.info("IDNS service started...");
            status="IDNS Service Started.";
        } else {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo\t/etc/init.d/idns   restart");
            logger.info("IDNS service restarted...");
            status="IDNS Service Restarted.";
        }
        return status;
```

Exception :-

```
      29-Jun-2015 03:18:54.511 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-381]        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for        servlet [idnsRulesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
      java.lang.NullPointerException
at    org.idnsrules.engine.activities.JSONTOyaml.jsonToYaml(JSONTOyaml.java:69)
at      org.idnsrules.engine.dao.IdnsRulesDAO.restartIdnsService(IdnsRulesDAO.java:258)
```

Comment: Try Like This.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java][1]

Comment: @ Ajith John this exception i am getting. javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/etc/init.d/idns status": error=2, No such file or directory
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)