# Java open Terminal with sudo

Tags: java, terminal, sudo

My Method:

```
public static void executeCommand(String command)
{
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("gnome-terminal", "-e", command).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I start the Terminal with sudo permission?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java