# How to provide Password for sudo command in java

Tags: java

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo rm -rf /home/ftp");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
bw.write("qwerty");
bw.flush();
```

I have written this code but it is not working

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you expect your program to do? in what way it is behaving different to you expectations?

Comment: Maybe change the code to something less desastrous, an "ftp" user might have a bad day when getting this to run ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute bash command with sudo privileges in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java)

Comment: If you want the process that runs your Java code to be able to remove the entire `/home/ftp` directory structure, grant the user that access. Don't go to god mode for that. Especially, **never** hardcode user password in a program. Your program should not know the user password. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] cmd = {"/bash/bin","-c"," echo password| sudo -S rm -rf /home/ftp"}; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
```

Provide the input for the process using the pipe.
Starting the `echo` with space it will remove it from bash history.

You can also later delete the history:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".bash_history").delete();
```

but be careful with it. There is a trick to remove just last entries.

Comment: Thats is **bad** advise: if you do it like this, everybody on the system that is allowed the "ps" command can **read** that password in plain text. You **never ever** put passwords directly into your command line.

Comment: Deleting .bash_history just makes a bad thing worse. If some random app deleted my history file, I'd be _very_ upset.

Answer (score 0):

Assign user the required permissions and also close the buffered writer by writing
     bw.close();
If you keep going for sudo mode then program may delete some important files that are required by other applications to work in a healthy way.