# Simulate touching a particular coordinates on screen

Tags: keypress, motion

I require a simple example of how to simulate a touch event on a particular coordinates on the android screen 
An example complete with declaration details would greatly help

I had attempted doing this but cannot get the syntax and declaration right

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb to get a shell into your device. First connect your device via USB or wifi to your computer, turn on Developer Options by tapping Build Number 7 times in settings app, then turn on adb debugging. If your ROM supports it you can use wifi debugging.

If you haven't done already, go get the latest adb binaries, for windows they are in the Google repository, for Linux you can use `pacman -S android-adb`

Then run `adb shell` and type `input touchscreen tap x y`

- X: x coordinate
- Y: y coordinate

You can get the coordinates by going to developer options and tuning on pointer location

Comment: konraditurbe, I am doing this coding on AIDE platform available on the android phone..Is there a simpler way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java

Comment: This is my main file