# How to execute sudo commands in Java and get error output?

Tags: java, command, sudo

So I've been trying to execute sudo commands on my Raspberry Pi via Java:

```
    try {
        Process p;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(`command`);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String output = "";
        while ((output = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        reader.close();

        p.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Process finished");
    }
```

This works for commands like `sudo ping google.com` or `sudo -V`. I get the correct output.

But with my Raspberry Pi, I actually want to send signals via a 433Mhz sender. While the needed commands like `sudo ~pi/raspberry-remote/send 11111 3 1` work totally fine when executed "by hand", the ***exact* same** code doesn't seem to work when executed via Java.

When executed by hand, I get 2 lines of output. If something's wrong with the command, I get an error output. But when executed via Java, I get no output at all. Not even an errror message. Even commands like `sudo hey123xy`, which are obviously not existant, dont give me any output in Java, although the console says, that this command does not exist.

1. Is there a way to read the error output of the console? (might be helpful for debugging)
2. How can I run sudo commands in Java?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I'm searching for a "secure" way of doing so. There are answers to similar questions, in which the author of the answer states, that he/she wouldn't recommend using the code in the answer.

Edit 2: After a few confusions... @Mehdi is right. The answer he/she linked helped me solving my problem. @Andreas posted a very helpful answer, so I'll mark this as the correct one...

Comment: Take a look at this answer -> [[How to execute bash command with sudo privileges in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708275/1970299)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708275/1970299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to read the error output

Yes, call [`p.getErrorStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--).

Better yet, use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and call [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-), so the error output is read from the `getInputStream()` data.