# launching script with sudo from java program

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, sudo

I have a requirement where I need to run a script in ubuntu with sudo on click of a button in swing UI.

In mac I just use the open command with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("open appname.app")`

and it launches a terminal asking me for the password and executes the script but in linux it doesnt work that way.

I've tried the solution in [How to execute bash command with sudo privileges in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java/18708275) but didn't work for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo mysudopassword| sudo -S <path of my script>"};
    Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    String line;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Even tried it this way as below

```
{"/bin/bash","-c","echo \"password\"| sudo -S ls"};
```

Is it possible to pass the password to sudo and then launch the script or open a terminal asking for the password  and then launch it ?

I'm using java8 with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Maybe try  *-A          Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user’s terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a
                 (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user’s password and output the password to the standard output.  If
                 the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper program. # Path to askpass helper program
                     Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass*

Comment: For more information on the askpass option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error, specifically rodrigo's answer.  I understand that question doesn't have java in it, but it's really just a sudo question.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Tried it with -A option but didn't work

Comment: see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352596/2310289