# How to control NGINX from a Java Web App?

Tags: java, nginx

To reload NGINX in terminal

Enter *sudo* then

```
nginx -t 
nginx -s reload
```

Are the commands to test and reload NGINX, however, how can this be done from a Java web application, which I need my web application to be able to control NGINX at least to test and reload.

Comment: You could use 

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nginx -t ")

Comment: @Chris Usage of Runtime.exec() is now discouraged: user shall use ProcessBuilder instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command using ProcessBuilder like below.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
// Run a shell command
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "nginx -t");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: this can only run with sudo

Comment: may be this thread could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java